# How to submit values of a modal and values outside of modal at the same time?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a modal with select value and when I post it I want to submit that values together with other values outside of the modal.

Here is the entire code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="myForm">
        <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all" type="checkbox" /></th>
                    <th>Client</th>                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                    
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<input type=hidden name=fetched_devices_array[] value=' . $row['device_id'] . '>' ?>
                                <?php echo '<input type=checkbox name=devices[] value=' . $row['dev_id'] . '>' ?>
                            </td>                               
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
                            </td>                               
                        </tr>
                    <div class="modal" id="acceptModal">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select the return to manufacturer</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                           
                                <p>
                                    <?php
                                    $sql_return_to = $db->prepare("SELECT
                                            users.id as user_id,
                                            users.full_name,
                                            users.role,
                                            companies.company_name
                                            FROM users
                                            INNER JOIN companies ON users.company_id=companies.id
                                            WHERE (users.role=? OR users.role=? OR users.role=? AND users.active=?)");
                                    $sql_return_to->bind_param("iiii", $usr_type1, $usr_type2, $usr_type3, $active);
                                    $sql_return_to->execute();
                                    $result_ = $sql_return_to->get_result();
                                    $result = [];
                                    if ($result_->num_rows > 0) {
                                        $result = $result_->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                                    }
                                    $sql_return_to->close();
                                    echo "<select class='device_manufacturer' name='device_manufacturer'>";
                                    $nothing = "Nothing selected";
                                    echo "<option value='" . $nothing . "'>" . $nothing . "</option>";
                                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                                        echo "<option value='" . $row['user_id'] . "'>" . $row['company_name'] . ' (' . explode(' ', trim($row['full_name']))[0] . ')' . "</option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>"; ?>
                                </p>
                            <div id="wrapper">
                                <button type="button" id="buttonConfirm" onclick="SubmitFormData()" name="goback" class="btn">Confirm</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

When I call :

```
 function SubmitFormData() {
        $("#myForm").submit(); // Submit the form
    }
```

I am able to receive in PHP all the values outside the modal but not the one from the dropdown `device_manufacturer` . Why does that happen?
P.S: There are values in the dropdown in case you are wondering if it might be empty.

Comment: Actually, why you have a second `<form>` in the modal?

Comment: @user13828103 sorry for that, I removed it. I tried like that but didn't work neither.

Comment: If you have everything inside the same form (including the contents of the modal), it should already submit everything.

Comment: @ttt, so with that (and the `</form>`) removed, what's the output of `var_dump( $_POST );` ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson everything is inside but its not submitting

Comment: @user13828103 Here it is: `array(4) { ["admin_comment"]=> string(0) "" ["example_length"]=> string(2) "10" ["fetched_devices_array"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "1140" [1]=> string(4) "1309" } ["devices"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "1140" } }`

Comment: Check the generated HTML to see if it looks funky for some reason. Otherwise I have no idea why it doesn't. Any form element inside the form tags that has a name (except from unchecked checkboxes) should be submitted. The fact that some elements are in a modal doesn't matter. A modal isn't a thing in HTML. It's just styling.

Comment: However, your HTML is invalid. You shouldn't have a `<div>` directly after a `</tr>`. Place the modal div right before the `<table>` line or right after `</table>` instead. Just make sure it's still inside the `<form></form>` tags. Don't know if that could affect anything more than making your HTML valid.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I moved it but unfortunately it didn't fix the issue

Comment: What did the generated HTML look like? Did you see anything strange? That's the only thing left I can think of.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just had an idea of using a hidden input outside the modal and whenever I select an option from the dropdown populate that hidden input with the selected value but I am not sure how can I achieve that?!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the generated html looks just fine to me

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I fixed it!! it was something wrong with the bootstrap styling because when I changed to another modal it does submit.

Comment: Nice. You should write your own answer, explaining the solution and then accept it. It might help others in a similar situation.